# Which unit I should use in CSS when designing a web page

Tags: html, css

I have designed and developed more than 10 sites, but I still have a doubt about the correct unit I should use. Should it be `px`, `em` or `%`?

**EDIT 1: FOR LAYOUTS (Especially for container boxes)**

Comment: Do you mean for font sizes or for layout dimensions?

Comment: Note: You will note that most graphic heavy sites use `px` for good reason.

Comment: Why you asked same question twice http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763698/what-unit-should-i-use-for-sizing-boxes-inside-wrapper-in-css You can edit your questions.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Different units depending on context. If there was one that was best for every situation, then there wouldn't be so many units.

As rules of thumb go:

If you are working on screen media:

- Use `%` for font sizes
- Use `px` for images
- Use `px`, `%`, or `em` for box sizes
- Use ratios for line height

If you are working in print media:

- It might be wise to avoid `px` (this is not a hard rule by any means) and everything else is fair game. It really depends how much control you want.

Comment: use `px` for images? which images? in HTML images `width` and `height` should be unit-less and in css there is no image related property.

Comment: I must have imagined background-image…

Comment: but this is property of box, does not control width and height of image.

Comment: It controls how much of an image is displayed, or if there is space beside the image. Sizing containers to fit background images is a very common requirement.

Comment: you are very right but in this condition we control box size not image size. you wrote "Use px for images". I think i'm thinking in other way. sorry.

Comment: What about `vh` and `vw`?

Answer (score 9):

There's no real right or wrong, but as a rule of thumb:

- For anything you want a certain, fixed size, use **PX**
- For anything you want to scale with font-size, use **EM**
- For anything you want to scale to the available space in the window/container, use **%**

Each used to have specific advantages or disadvantages in different browsers when it came to users scaling the browser's base font-size/zooming, but more recent versions of the browsers by-and-large get around these issues by scaling everything, not just font-size.

Answer (score 2):

If you're talking about font-size then px and pt are not ideal.

Ems and Percent units are scalable, therefore they are far more accessible - friendly for the visually-impaired. They also scale down well for mobile phone users.

Px and Pt units do not scale upward for visually-impaired users, or downward for mobile phones.

If you're talking about layout or containers then it depends on the type of design you want - fluid or static - and there isn't necessarily a "right" answer.

Without going into an example, it's difficult to advice. Do you have a site in mind we could look at?

Comment: Totally agree with this. Font-sizes should ideally be set with ems.

Answer (score 0):

Use the unit you need in the specific context.

```
Unit   Description
====================
%   percentage
in  inch
cm  centimeter
mm  millimeter
em  1em is equal to the current font size. 2em means 2 times the size of the current font. E.g., if an element is displayed with a font of 12 pt, then '2em' is 24 pt. The 'em' is a very useful unit in CSS, since it can adapt automatically to the font that the reader uses
ex  one ex is the x-height of a font (x-height is usually about half the font-size)
pt  point (1 pt is the same as 1/72 inch)
pc  pica (1 pc is the same as 12 points)
px  pixels (a dot on the computer screen)
```

*source:* http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_units.asp

Answer (score 0):

For flexibility and accessibility I recommend using `%` for horizontal measures (relative to the user's screen), and `em` for vertical measures (relative to the user's font setting).

Comment: If you're working with a fluid layout, true. However, it's hard to maintain fluid layouts for all but the simplest sites. Graphics don't tend to scale as well.

Answer (score 0):

**For fixed width layouts**

For as much as pixel perfection I would suggest to use `PX` for width ,height, margin, and padding

for `line-height` use unit-less value like `{line-height:1.2}`

for typographic elemets use `{font-size:62.5%)` for `body` then use `em` for other elements

in HTML for `<img>` always use unit-less width and height .

Comment: Starting with font-size:62.5% is not a good idea. It just gives the illusion of working in pixels when you are using ems (which falls down as soon as a user has chosen defaults different from the ones the browser vendor picked).

Comment: @David Dorward - You are right but that type of user's percentage is very low. It's not a very good idea and not much bad idea.