# CSS - What is best to use for this case (px, %, vw, wh or em)?

Tags: html, css, ionic2

I am using Ionic 2 for the development of an app and I need to preview the app in different sizes.

Currently, I am using `vw` in all the sizes including `font-size`, `padding` and so on, but when resizing the font it sometimes becomes a bit small and even sometimes the text is not readable.

For that reason, I would like to know what is best to use in this case:

- `px`
- `%`
- `vw`
- `wh`
- `em`

Or do I need to use also the `@media` and support different font sizes?

Any thoughts?

Comment: you may use @media and vh / vw, so you can avoid vw / vh to be too small or too big and let them work in between your safe breaking points where you can use either rem, em, px, pt, cm, ... ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [which unit i should use in CSS, while designing web page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763591/which-unit-i-should-use-in-css-while-designing-web-page)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Note that I only mentioned the ones you asked about.

Here you can see the full list of CSS measurement units: [CSS Units in W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp)

Rather than telling you which one is the "right one", I would rather want you to understand what each one actually is.

**Pixels (`px`):** Absolute pixels. So for example, `20px` will be literally 20 pixels on any screen. If a monitor is of 1980x1200, and you set an element's height to `200px`, the element will take 200 pixels out of that.

**Percentage (`%`):** Relative to the parent value.

So for this example:

```
<div style="width: 200px;">
    <div style="width: 50%;"></div>
</div>
```

The inner div will have a width of 100 pixels.

**Viewport height/width (`vw`/`vh`):** Size relative to the viewport (browser window, basically).

Example:

```
.myDiv {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: red;
}
```

Will make an cover the whole browser in red. This is very common among [flexboxes](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) as it's naturally responsive.

**Emeters (`em`) and Root Emeters (`rem`):** `em` is relative to the parent element's font size. `rem` will be relative to the `html` font-size (mostly 16 pixels). This is very useful if you want to keep an "in mind relativity of sizes" over your project, and not using variables by pre-processors like Sass and Less. Just easier and more intuitive, I guess.

Example:

```
.myDiv {
    font-size: 0.5rem;
}
```

Font size will be 8 pixels.

Now that you know, choose the right one for the right purpose.

Comment: you have also cm, pt (more for print purpose i agree), mind that vh, vw do not care about the scrollbars being there or not ;)

Comment: @GCyrillus I could mention all of them, but I chose to only talk about the specific ones that the OP asked about :)

Comment: it gives him more to learn about ;)

Comment: @GCyrillus Correct, and after reading your commend I also edited and added a source to see all units available.

Comment: i saw this and upvoted :)

Comment: The point about pixels is incorrect. pixel is not equal to physical pixel, but 1 css pixel. Which is dependent upon window.devicePixelRatio (This setting matters especially for mobiles). Search for css pixels vs physical pixels

Answer (score 2):

[w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp) has a pretty nice summary about css units.

I for myself do always use **em**. Why?

First of all, **em** is relative to your `font-size`. So as w3school says, `2em` would be **2 times** of the `font-size` you've defined in your **parent container**. So you may define a specific `font-size` for your `html` tag and use whatever em you want, to handle relative `font-sizes` for various tasks.

Also, **em** is covered in mostly all browsers.

At least, you may use `@media-queries` to handle responsive `font-size` handling for mobile devices. So you may consider using `@media-queries` combined with a relative `font-size` by using **em**.

Comment: W3schools it is really not a good reference

Comment: W3Schools is a very good reference

Comment: @Suamere we use MDN now :p

Comment: duality of man.

Answer (score 1):

this is probably gonna get closed, but I love using the em units because they are very scale-able, esp in mobile browsers that being said, I do use media queries along with them. I really depends on what youre doing.

A good site will probably compose of a few ems and a few pxs ratio, so what ever your end goal is will should dictate which you'll use,

if you 
understand each ones application youll be able to end up with which one you like more. W3Schools and W3code both have good articles on them...